# How would I print the title property in this returned JSON in Swift using URLSession and dataTask?

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I am working with an api and getting back some strangely formatted JSON.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Wales' new £2bn space strategy hopes",
        "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-60433763",
        "source": "bbc"
    },
    {
        "title": "Could Port Talbot become a centre of space tech? Video, 00:02:02Could Port Talbot become a centre of space tech?",
        "url": "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-60471170",
        "source": "bbc"
    },
]
```

As you can see, there is no object name I can latch on to. I've tried making a model like this

```
struct SpaceNewsModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let title: String
    let url: String
    let source: String   
}
```

But once I get to using `JSONDeocder()` with the following code

```
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let astroNews = try decoder.decode(SpaceNewsModel.self, from: safeData)
                        print(astroNews)
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("DEBUG: Error getting news articles \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
```

I get the error `DEBUG: Error getting news articles The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

So how would you go about printing out each title, url, or source to the console? I've worked with JSON before and they are usually formatted differently.

Comment: There is nothing strange about that json, it’s an array. So decode it as an array of your struct

Comment: Also when handing a decoding error don’t use error.localizedDescription instead print the error object directly, `print(error)`, and you get a much more detailed error message

Comment: `decode(SpaceNewsModel.self` => `decode([SpaceNewsMode]l.self`, as said, you have an array, not an dictionary at top level.

Comment: I have tried using [SpaceNewsModel] and I get the error “the data could not be found.” I have also tried using a strict within a struct. I tried array, multiple structs. It just doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. Removing the identifiable protocol lets me access the data. Like so

```
struct SpaceNewsModel: Codable {

    let title: String
    let url: String
    let source: String
    
}
```

Then I can use decoder as normal

```
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let astroNews = try decoder.decode([SpaceNewsModel].self, from: safeData)
                        
                        print(astroNews[0].title)

                        
                    } catch {
                        print("DEBUG: Error getting news articles \(error)")
                    }
                }
```

I did change `let astroNews = try decoder.decode(SpaceNewsModel.self, from: safeData)`  to `let astroNews = try decoder.decode([SpaceNewsModel].self, from: safeData)`

Even with changing it to array type or not, as long as I had my SpaceNewsModel following the identifiable protocol, it would NOT work. It's a strange workaround, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to

```
 let astroNews = try decoder.decode([SpaceNewsModel].self, from: safeData)
```

use this common approach for your `SpaceNewsModel`. Having it `Identifiable` is very useful in SwiftUI.

```
struct SpaceNewsModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here, a let
    
    let title: String
    let url: String
    let source: String  

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { // <-- here 
         case title,url,source 
    }
 
}
```